# Anchor ImageView to Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, imageview, anchor, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When a FloatingActionButton is anchored to a CollapsingToolbarLayout, it disappears when you scroll up, reappears when you scroll down after a certain point. I was wondering if you can do that with any type of view. In my app, I'm trying to anchor an ImageView to the CollapsingToolbarLayout but it won't disappear like the FloatingActionButton. Here's the XML code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="252dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/random"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.example.sudarshan.testapp.MLRoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    android:id="@+id/circularImage"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The ImageView gets anchored but it does not disappear and reappear like the FAB does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behaviour of disappearing and appearing of View is only associated with `FAB`(`FloatingActionButton`).
You should have a look on the source code of class `FloatingActionButton`.
Here is the method in `Behavior` class , inner class of `FloatingActionButton`which is responsible for the behaviour.

```
@Override
        public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child,
                View dependency) {
            if (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
                updateFabTranslationForSnackbar(parent, child, dependency);
            } else if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                // If we're depending on an AppBarLayout we will show/hide it automatically
                // if the FAB is anchored to the AppBarLayout
                updateFabVisibility(parent, (AppBarLayout) dependency, child);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**Edit**

You can extend the class `FloatingActionButton` to achieve what I think you need.

I have extended as follows-

```
/**
 * Sked Series, All rights Reserved
 * Created by Sanjeet on 06-Jan-16.
 */
public class FloatingActionImageView extends FloatingActionButton {
    public FloatingActionImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FloatingActionImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FloatingActionImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sBmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sBmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius + 5, radius + 5);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2,
                radius / 2, radius / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sBmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (b != null) {
            bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        } else {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(com.sked.dd.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, null));
            } else {
                bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(com.sked.dd.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery));
            }
            if (bitmapDrawable != null) {
                bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        int w = getWidth();
        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);


    }
}
```

And here is the output -

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Really a fantastic solution. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Tested and working well

```
public class RoundedImage extends FloatingActionButton {

public RoundedImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RoundedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    int scaledWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int scaledHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
    if (scaledWidth == fullSizeBitmap.getWidth()
            && scaledHeight == fullSizeBitmap.getHeight()) {
        mScaledBitmap = fullSizeBitmap;
    } else {
        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullSizeBitmap,
                scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true );
    }



    Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircledBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input,
                                     int pixels, int w, int h, boolean     squareTL, boolean squareTR,
                                     boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR) {

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density;

    final int color = 0xff424242;

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    // make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
    final float roundPx = pixels * densityMultiplier;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    // draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
    if (squareTL) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareTR) {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareBL) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, h / 2, w / 2, h, paint);
    }
    if (squareBR) {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, h / 2, w, h, paint);
    }

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, paint);

    return output;
}

Bitmap getCircledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);






    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

    int color = Color.BLUE;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
//        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2,     bitmap.getHeight()/2, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);



    return result;
}

}
```

Then call it in xml

```
  <yourPackageName.RoundedImage
    android:id="@+id/singleCompLogo"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.4"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
    android:src="@mipmap/image" />
```

Replace yourPackageName with YOUR PACKAGE NAME

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in your Toolbar xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
....
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Check [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-collapsing-effects)

I hope it's helps you.