# Overlay part of an imageview over toolbar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to overlay part of an image view over a toolbar as shown in the below image.

[image]

I have tried using a custom floating action button (using a rectangular canvas) described by Sanjeet Ajnabee [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632497/anchor-imageview-to-collapsing-toolbar). But, I want only a part of the image to be on the toolbar unlike a floating action button.

Using a dialog wouldn't work as well. I want the image to be part of the layout.

Any idea to start with will help.

Comment: can you post your XML layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple, you just use a `NoActionBar` style and then a Layout like the pseudo-XML below:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <Toolbar height="60dp" paddingBottom="12dp"> // here is the Toolbar
   <ImageView marginTop="48dp" /> // marging top = 60-12=48
   <FrameLayout marginTop="60dp">
        // add here the rest of your layout
   </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.