# Anchor imageview to the collapsing toolbar in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-design-library

I am trying to make a layout like [this](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/scene-club-booking-interaction) where I am adding collapsing toolbar functionality I searched lots of solution to achive this kind of animation where the below layout slides up and with that it takes the image[portrait] also with the animation.

**What I have achieved till now**

- I am able to slide the below layout.
- I am able to collapse the toolbar.
- I am able to show my Tab views into the toolbar

**What I want to achieve**

- When I slide the below layout my image gets stuck in half way and it doesn't go completely up and hide.

**Solution which I am not looking for**

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632497/anchor-imageview-to-collapsing-toolbar) thread tell how to hide and show the imageview when we slide the child layout but my requirement is not hiding the Imageview I just want to slide the view on the top.

Below is my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
[![enter image description here][2]][2]<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/posterbackdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_collapseMode="none" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

        <nseit.com.tmdb.Common.FontTypeFace
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:transitionName="moviename"
            app:typeface="roboto_bold" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/MyTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/TabLayout_Theme"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/movieportrait"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/TextColor" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/movieportrait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:cardElevation="15dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarlayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/deadpoolpotrait"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:scaleY="1.2" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Attaching the screenshot [image: Below]

Comment: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator go through this tutorial ..!!! Its really helpful .

Comment: I think you need to place your `deadpoolPotrait` inside your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: @Meet if I do that The portrait view goes inside the backdrop view and doesn't covert the two layout view like it is doing right now.